# Taylor coefficients of $e^{-\pi n^2e^{2x}}$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to write down a closed form expression for the Taylor series of the function $e^{-\pi n^2 e^{2x}}$ expanded at $x=0$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

Differentiating explicitly one finds that

$$e^{-\pi n^2 e^{2x}} = e^{-\pi n^2}(1-2\pi n^2x+2\pi n^2 (\pi n^2-1)x^2-\frac{4}{3}\pi n^2 (\pi^2 n^4-3\pi n^2+1)x^3+O(x^4))$$

From here one can conclude that the general term $\frac{c_m x^n}{m!}$, in the Taylor series, satisfies $c_m \neq 0$, since $\pi$ is trancendental and $c_m$ contains at worst polynomial factors.
I have also tried the usual composition of Taylor series, but i cannot obtain any more information on $c_m$.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Taylor series has coefficients you mentioned across the 0. The only way to avoid $\pi$ may be expansion of this function across some other point I would suggest $\ln[1/\pi]$.

Comment: Expanding at $\ln(1/\sqrt{\pi})$ one obtains exactly the same as the expansion i wrote above with the $\pi$ terms deleted, and $x \to x+0.5\ln(\pi)$. This doesnt help that much to find the general form of $c_m$, but, thank you, it simplifies!

Comment: I am not sure that the expected coefficients will be rational or even algebraic. Even more I assume that the only way to get the rational coefficients is expansion around the transcendental point. Even in that case the simplicity you are looking for is not always possible.

Comment: $c_m$ will be polynomials in $\pi n^2$, since we are repeatedly differentiating $e^{-\pi n^2 e^{2x}}$. However there is no clear indication as to the form they take. I was assuming there was formula given by a product but I cannot quite write it down.

Comment: Then I should be misunderstood you. Please take a look at the Faa Di Bruno formula this will solve the issue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much !

Comment: Note the expansion of $\theta(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ at $x=0$ is obtained from $\theta(x) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} \zeta(s) \pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) x^{-s}ds$ and the functional equation, ie. $1+2\theta(x)  = x^{-1/2}(1+2\theta(1/x))$

Comment: @reuns I think this questions corresponds ( if one takes the sum as you proposed ) to the expansion of the theta function at $x=1$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding $e^{te^x}$ on the outer exponential first, and then on the inner exponential, and finally switching order of summations gives
$$\begin{align}
e^{t e^x}
& = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!} \left(t e^x \right)^m \\
& = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!} t^m e^{mx} \\
& = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!} t^m \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} (mx)^k \right) \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} \left( \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{m!} m^k \right) \\
\end{align}$$

The inner parenthesis can now be written as
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{m!} m^k = \left(t\frac{d}{dt}\right)^k e^t = p_k(t) e^t,$$
where $p_k(t)$ are polynomials satisfying $p_0(t) = 1$ and $p_{k+1}(t) = t \left( p_k'(t) + p_k(t) \right).$ I don't know if there is an explicit formula for the coefficients of these polynomials.

Thus,
$$e^{t e^x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} p_k(t) e^t = e^t \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} p_k(t)$$
and
$$
e^{-\pi n^2 e^{2x}} 
= e^{-\pi n^2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^k}{k!} p_k(-\pi n^2) 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k e^{-\pi n^2} p_k(-\pi n^2) }{k!} x^k.
$$
i.e. the coefficient of $x^k$ is
$$c_k = \frac{2^k e^{-\pi n^2} p_k(-\pi n^2)}{k!}.$$

Comment: I have reproduced your proof, apart from the step $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{m!}m^k=(t\frac{d}{dt})^k e^t$. How do you deduce this ?

Comment: The series $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{m!} = e^t$ is well-known. Then notice that $(d \frac{d}{dt})^k t^m = m^k t^m$ and you are done.